# unable to download dynamic library

Tags: php, php-openssl

I want to install Composer on my Ubuntu 14.04LTS. But during installation I got this:

Some settings on your machine make composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The OpenSSL extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl

Then in php.ini I remove semicolon';' in line ;extension=php_openssl.dll
After this I've got:

```
     PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_openssl.dll' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_openssl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.6.2 (cli) (built: Oct 29 2014 06:55:23) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

Where can I get this library?

Answer (score 0):

You use php.ini from windows machine. Use default from package manager. For Ubuntu apt-get.

Comment: I use /usr/local/php.ini file. Where could I get this one for ubuntu apt-get

Comment: Found. I shuld use php5 instead of php in /usr/bin/php5 and everything works